# Using transaction workspaces with Access linked to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, transactions, workspace

I started developing an Access 2010 database application using DAO, but soon realised that the 2GB size limit for Access would not be enough. I converted the Access front end to use linked tables in SQL server 2014 using the built in wizard, and successfully managed to get everything working exactly the same, except for one thing. The application loads individual files from a folder into 8 or 9 tables (both updates and inserts), so to maintain database integrity I use the workspace method BeginTrans before each file is processed then either CommitTrans or Rollback depending on whether the file load was successful or not.

This worked fine when it was an Access database but does not work when the tables are linked ones to an SQL server database, Access hangs while processing the second transaction (ie file). If I remove the workspace code everything works perfectly OK (except of course if a file fails I have a half updated database).

I am not clear on what to do to resolve this, probably because I don't understand enough about the way ODBC/Access/SQL server actually work, I'm not even sure if the linked tables I have in Access are linked through ODBC or not, I just followed the wizard!

I really do need transactional processing as there is finance involved. I have read suggestions about using ADO, although no-one has described having exactly the same problem that I have, so before I embark on doing this is that the right thing to do, or are there other alternatives?

Comment: Bulk insert (would be direct to the underlying sql tables) might be worth an investigation.

Comment: When you upload a file does it go directly from a file to a SQL table? Or does it go File > intermediate table > validation via SQL > final SQL table? i.e. you might be able to not need transactions if you write your code in a way that can see errors before they are even inserted.

Comment: I think the only two ways to do this is through ADO or sending the whole batch together to be executed natively by SQL Server.  With ADO, you can begin a transaction on the Connection object and theoretically go through each file in code, keeping that same connection open (but maybe bad practice - you may end up locking SS's resources and preventing other tx's from going through) and rolling back if you deem it necessary.  Else, you could go through each file beforehand, put together all the SQL for the batch wrapped in a transaction, and execute it via ADO or a pass-through query.

Comment: Not sure about bulk insert, there are too many updates as well as inserts. The file is straight into the linked tables I don't use intermediate ones. It is a possibility, but personally I don't like it, I would rather the language or database did that for me. So if it can't be done in DAO I am tending towards ADO so far. Are there any reasons I shouldn't use ADO?

Comment: There is no issue with using ADO to do what you want - it is very mature and still used frequently.  Take a look here to see if there are any gotchas with your situation - ADODB.BeginTrans vs. SQL Server BEGIN TRANSACTION : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198024